# ORA-24408: could not generate unique server group name

Tags: php, oracle

system:

```
Linux web 2.6.27.21-0.1-pae #1 SMP 2009-03-31 14:50:44 +0200 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

PHP Version 5.3.8
Apache Version  Apache/2.2.21 (Linux/SUSE)
OCI8 Support    enabled
Version     1.4.7
Revision    $Revision: 321634 $
Active Persistent Connections   0
Active Connections  0
Oracle Run-time Client Library Version  11.2.0.3.0
Oracle Instant Client Version   11.2
```

when calling `oci_connect` - receiv

> ORA-24408: could not generate unique server group name

can`t understand what the kind error is this and howto fix it.

Comment: http://nickshontz.wordpress.com/2011/11/29/php-oracle/

Comment: Sérgio Michels - thanks, i`ll try

Comment: Sérgio Michels - it works tnx

Comment: Ok, I put this as an answer, so others can see that this question have a solution :)

Answer (score 46):

You can downgrade to 10g if you want (it evidently doesn't care about this) but that's not necessary...

The 11g instant client requires a `/etc/hosts` file entry for your hostname pointing to 127.0.0.1. The normal "localhost" entry is not sufficient on it's own.

Assuming your host name is `foomachine`, there are two places you'll need to check:

In `/etc/hosts`, make sure you have any entry like - add it if it's not there:

```
127.0.0.1   foomachine
```

And also make sure the `/etc/sysconfig/network` file also has `HOSTNAME=foomachine`

That should do the trick.

Comment: Awesome, you saved my day. Yhank you very much.

Comment: I can confirm this fixed the issue on my setup (Mac OS X 10.8.4). On Mac OS X, I only had to add the entry to the `/etc/hosts` file, and retry the command and it worked. Strangely, I had been using the same code without issue for several weeks before this issue arose, but I'm glad it only needed a simple fix. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: It also works with one of the real network interfaces IPs, does not need 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Seems my hostname has changed. I found it by running "hostname" in terminal. Then I added new hostname to my current hosts file with updating the 127.0.0.1 line.

Comment: Script: `echo "127.0.0.1 $(hostname)" >> /etc/hosts` as superuser.

Comment: Is there any way to make this the new accepted answer?  7 years later this just saved the day.

Answer (score 4):

Kind of an old question, but I just stumbled on it after upgrading my Mac to Sierra. Until then I hadn't had the problem.

The trick is definitely to add your hostname to /etc/hosts, but you have to have the right hostname. That's easy on linux, it's in /etc/sysconfig/network. On Mac find it in System Preferences > Sharing.  Under where it says Computer name will be something like computer-name.local. In /etc/hosts put

```
   127.0.0.1 computer-name.local
```

Replacing computer-name with your computer name of course :).  **It needs this regardless of whether the database is a remote one or a local one.**

I had plenty of other aliases for 127.0.0.1 but not that one. As soon as I added that one my apps started working again.

Answer (score 1):

In my situation, the OracleDB server I was trying to connect to was a remote one, not a local one, so the above `127.0.0.1 localhost` trick didn't work.

Previously, I had temporarily fixed a DNS problem by adding an entry for my Oracle DB server into my hosts file.
This IP in my hosts file *was still correct* - it still pointed to the correct OracleDB server IP.

**By removing the entry from my hosts file, the problem went away.**

I have no idea why this is a problem for OracleDB, or why the error message is so obtuse, but I hope this helps someone else.

(This was using InstantClient v12.1.0.2 on MacOS v10.11.5)

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem.  I fixed my /etc/hosts and /etc/sysconfig/network file and RESTARTED THE NETWORK and it works fine now.  Here are some quick and dirty instructions:

http://ahmadzainuddinzakaria.blogspot.com/2012/06/warning-ociconnect-functionoci-connect.html

Answer (score 0):

In CentOS 6.5 I changed the value of the file: `/etc/sysconfig/network`

Original value:

```
HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain
```

New value:

```
HOSTNAME=127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually **do not need** to go with `127.0.0.1` in `/etc/hosts` with something like

```
echo -e "127.0.0.1\t$HOSTNAME" >> /etc/hosts
```

which is against common sense (and formally against [RFC 6761](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6761) only from February 2013 ).

Luckily it will also work if you only have your real IP address registered - something like

```
192.0.2.5 mymachine.example.net
```

which is btw frequently missing in virtual machines created with DHCP.

or - the last resort scenario - use some other IP address from 127.0.0.0/8

```
127.0.1.1 mymachine.example.net
```

Tested with *Oracle Instant Client 11.2* .

Sysadmins dealing with weird stuff like Legato Backup will thank you for not messing with `/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to /etc/hosts resolved the issue.

```
127.0.0.1 someHostName
```

To find your computer's host name, just type hostname in Terminal. Use a text editor such as vim to edit hosts.

```
~ hostname
someHostName
~ cd /etc
/etc sudo vim hosts
```