# How to connect to a remote Oracle 11g database using PHP

Tags: php, oracle, ubuntu

I have tried to make `oci_connect` work, by following [these directions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PHPOracle), but I still get the error:

> ora-24408 could not generate unique server group name in test.php

Here is my PHP snippet (with bogus IP):

```
   $tns2 = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 123.123.123.123)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = foo)))";
   if ($conn = oci_connect("username","pwd", $tns2))
   {
       echo "Connected to foo";
       oci_close($conn);
   }
   else
   {
       die("could not connect to foo");
   }
```

I use SQL Developer and can connect to this database just fine from this Ubuntu server. I also have Java applications that connect from this Ubuntu server to the remote Oracle database without any problems.

What am I missing to make PHP work?

I even did the `phpinfo()` and it showed the oci8 information.

Comment: This is unrelated to what you're asking about but I'm assuming you made a typographical error when you typed: `(PROTOCAL = TCP)` - I'm assuming you meant `(PROTOCOL = TCP)`.

Comment: good eyes... yes I made a typo in my post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a closer look to [oci_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php).

And try with this conection string: `"123.123.123.123:1521/foo"`

```
$conn = oci_connect("username","pwd", "123.123.123.123:1521/foo");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: nope tried that too... still get error ora-24408 could not generate unique server group name in test.php line 75

Comment: @Dean-O, Check on this [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484231/ora-24408-could-not-generate-unique-server-group-name#answer-10710126).

Comment: bingo, that did the trick... no /etc/hosts entry and also no file sysconfig/nextwork

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
define ('DB_USER','username');
define ('DB_PASS','pwd');
define ('DB_HOST', '123.123.123.123');
define ('DB_NAME', 'YOUR_DATABASE_NAME');
define ('CONST_DB_CHARSET_FOR_CONNECT','WE8ISO8859P15');
define ('DB_CONNECTION_STRING','\\123.123.123.123/DBSCHEMA');//in localhost use ''


$conexion = oci_connect(DB_USER, DB_PASS,DB_CONNECTION_STRING,CONST_DB_CHARSET_FOR_CONNECT);
```

Just put the right value for: YOUR_DATABASE_NAME
that's how I connect to remote oracle 11.g database.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: What is your define for DB_CONNECTION_STRING