# How can I connect to an external (another server) Oracle Database using PHP?

Tags: php, oracle

I am having a hard time trying to find out how can I connect from my clients eshop to the "ERP's" database which is an Oracle database.
I have everything I need like the connection string ,usernames, passwords etc.
I am trying to connect from my webserver which is whitelisted by the way and it throws errors like

Call to undefined function oci_connect() . I have asked the hosting company and they weren't pretty sure about it. They have enabled a library for me however this wasn't enough.

I can't figure out what I should do. I have connected to remote databases some times but all them were MySQL servers.

Comment: We really can't help you find what's wrong with your code without being able to see it - though that error does sound like you/they don't have OCI8 installed for php to make use of the functions in it.

Comment: You mean this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096203/how-to-connect-to-a-remote-oracle-11g-database-using-php

Comment: Well they have oci8 installed and activated on the server but the issue remains.

Comment: If it were activated, you wouldn't get the 'undefined function' error.  Don't forget   PHP OCI8 will need Oracle Client libraries, e.g from Oracle Instant Client. Check the [OCI8 manual](https://www.php.net/manual/book.oci8.php) and [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/underground-php-oracle-manual.html)