# Oracle node OID generation failed

Tags: node.js, oracle

Tried to access remote database using node. Here is my code

```
var oracle = require('oracle');
var cntdata = {
hostname: "xyz.sv3.corp.xxx.com",
port: 1521,
database: "qa.sv3.corp.xxx.com",
user: "xxx",
password: "xxxx"
}
oracle.connect(cntdata, function(error,connection){
if(error){console.log(error);
return console.log("connectivity failed");
}
connection.execute("SELECT systimestamp FROM dual", [], function(err, results) {
        if (err) { console.log("Error executing query:", err); return; }

        console.log(results);
        connection.close(); // call only when query is finished executing
    });
});
```

I also made entry in /etc/hosts file as 172.20.200.00 xyz.sv3.corp.xxx.com

when i execute app.js it fails with Error: ORA-21561: OID generation failed....Please help!

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484231/ora-24408-could-not-generate-unique-server-group-name). If you're using the 11g instant client you need an entry in `/etc/hosts` for 127.0.0.1. You also need an entry in `/etc/sysconfig/network` for `HOSTNAME=foomachine` (if your computer is, in fact, called `foomachine` :-). Best of luck.

Comment: It worked thnx.. I made entry only in /etc/hosts for local machine name

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed with a simple edit of your hosts file:

Find out name of your localhost system by just typing 'hostname' in terminal/Command Prompt. Let's assume your machine is called 'the_machine' then edit your /etc/hosts file to : 127.0.0.1       localhost       the_machine

1. $hostname :

   the_machine
2. $vi /etc/hosts :

   127.0.0.1       localhost       the_machine
3. $python Connect_to_Oracle_DB.py

Cheers!