# Error: ORA-24408: could not generate unique server group name

Tags: node.js, oracle, centos, centos7, oracle12c

Getting this error when trying to bring up nodejs application. ORA-24408: could not generate unique server group name.

I checked all the necessary details and everything seems to be fine. Not sure whether i missed anything or need to configure somewhere.

Below are output of hosts configurations file.

```
cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
<gave my machine ip> inches-rmtest01.aaitg.com

cat /etc/hostname
inches-rmtest01

cat /etc/sysconfig/network
# Created by anaconda
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=inches-rmtest01
```

I have oracle 12.1 client installed and configured tnsnames.ora as below.

```
[rmtest01@inches-rmtest01 admin]$ cat tnsnames.ora
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File:

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <gave ip where oracle db is installed>)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

Below are my sqlplus version

```
[rmtest01@inches-rmtest01 admin]$ sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Sun Jul 17 16:54:55 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name:
```

Below is the database version we are trying to connect

```
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-24408: could not generate unique server group name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484231/ora-24408-could-not-generate-unique-server-group-name)

Comment: @HAL9000. no its not. i tried all the options from given link.

Comment: I don't know why, but it seems Oracle client needs to have your hostname in /etc/hosts like that: 127.0.0.1 localhost inches-rmtest01